# How to make empty canvas in JES/Python

Tags: python, jython, jes

Create an empty picture with dimensions 350x350

I came up with this:

```
def makeNewCanvas():
    canvas = makeEmptyPicture(350, 350)
```

it does nothing please help

Comment: Can you please show more of your code; place your problem in context.

Comment: it is from a text book and that is the only thing i get

Comment: Yes, but how are you going to use it. Where is the code that calls it

Comment: it will just be used on its own to create a new fresh canvas that will be painted onto later on

Answer (score 0):

When you call `makeNewCanvas()` in the command area it will create the blank picture and do nothing else.

To see what you have created:

```
def makeNewCanvas():
  canvas = makeEmptyPicture(350, 350)
  show(canvas)
```

Then call `makeNewCanvas()` in the command line.